# Why is my React Text component showing no text? (React 360)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in React:

```
  export class CryptoInformation extends React.Component {


  state = {
    cryptoInformation: {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({cryptoInformation: response["data"]});
    })
    .then(response => {

      #########This logs to the console 'Bitcoin'#######
      console.log(this.state.cryptoInformation.name);


    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>

        ######## Why is this not showing 'Bitcoin' #######
        <Text>{this.state.cryptoInformation.name}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

The API works perfectly and I am able to get the information I need to be stored in my `cryptoInformation` object. However, when I try to display the `name` portion of the JSON, I get nothing for the Text. Why is this so? This should be straightforward. Am I presenting the data wrong? Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

----Edit----

The data that is returned has the following structure:

```
{
"data": {
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "Bitcoin", 
    "symbol": "BTC", 
    "website_slug": "bitcoin", 
    "rank": 1, 
    "circulating_supply": 17008162.0, 
    "total_supply": 17008162.0, 
    "max_supply": 21000000.0, 
    "quotes": {
        "USD": {
            "price": 9024.09, 
            "volume_24h": 8765400000.0, 
            "market_cap": 153483184623.0, 
            "percent_change_1h": -2.31, 
            "percent_change_24h": -4.18, 
            "percent_change_7d": -0.47
        }
    }, 
    "last_updated": 1525137271
},
"metadata": {
    "timestamp": 1525237332, 
    "error": null
}
```

}

Also, I have no errors as I can see the data structure in the console.

-----EDIT----

I left out a major detail. I am actually using React 360 for creating a Vr web page. Sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: How does your response["data"] look like. Can you do console log and share the data or atleast it's struture

Comment: Does this resolve your problem? `state = {
    cryptoInformation: { name : '' }
  }`

Comment: Can you do console.log of state in render()??

Comment: I don't get any errors at all. I want to use other aspects of the data so I can't just use the name as you've suggested.

Comment: @pritesh. I did the `console.log` in render and the structure is present. For some reason it just doesn't show up in the Text component.

Comment: Your code works fine at my end.

Comment: @DanRubio i have used same code and its working fine in my system

Comment: Sorry everyone, I suppose it would  make a huge difference to mention that I'm using react360 for creating a VR experience :\

Comment: Without knowing what `<View>` and `<Text>` are doing it would be very difficult to debug. The code seems pretty standard React and `fetch` code so nothing too wrong in that.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same way but not getting any error, its working as expected.

Only thing i have changed is am using `<div>` insted `<View>`, `<h1>` instead of `<Text>`.
since its a react app.

You have to check weather are you importing this file correctly or not.

```js
class CryptoInformation extends React.Component {


  state = {
    cryptoInformation: {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({cryptoInformation: response["data"]});
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(this.state.cryptoInformation.name);


    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.cryptoInformation.name}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <CryptoInformation/>,
 document.getElementById("root")
 );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @Isa4299, thanks for the answer. Sorry I didn't mention this but I am using React 360. Normally this would work in normal react I agree.

Comment: but everything is fine from `react` side, you have to check only in `react-360`'s `<View>` and `<Text>`